# Should I put methods to get location and permissions in the fragment or main activity?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm creating an android weather app that fetches json from a server. I got it to work on a blank activity, but decided to turn my layout into a tabbed layout, which changes much of the way the project is structured. On one tab, I plan to have the json weather data, but I'm not sure where to put the methods to get location and permissions. Would it go into my tabbed fragment or my main activity?

Right now, the methods are in my tabbed fragment, and every time I try to request data, I get a EPERM (Operation not permitted) error. I made sure to have all my permission intents in my manifest, and all the permissions functions work correctly, as my program was able to get all the data before I changed layouts.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.Manifest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.ConsoleMessage;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.stratus_weather_the_final_chapter.data.WeatherOutputData;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.jackson.JacksonConverterFactory;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Frag1.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Frag1#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Frag1 extends Fragment  {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    public Button sendButton;
    TextView  description, tempTextView, cityNameTextView, humidityTextView, pressureTextView, windSpeedTextView;
    private WebView MapsView;
    public double lat, lon;

    ImageView weatherIcon;

    public Frag1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Frag1.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Frag1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Frag1 fragment = new Frag1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag1, container, false);
        sendButton = v.findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        pressureTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.pressureTextView);
        windSpeedTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.windSpeedTextView);
        humidityTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.humidityTextView);
        cityNameTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.cityNameTextView);
        description = v.findViewById(R.id.descriptionTextView);
        tempTextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tempTextView);

        getLocationPermission();
        getDeviceLocation();


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.openweathermap.org")
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        final WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);

        final WeatherForcast forcast = retrofit.create(WeatherForcast.class);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Call<WeatherOutputData> callRequest = service.getWeatherInfo(Double.toString(lat), Double.toString(lon), "imperial", "API_KEY");
                Call<WeatherOutputData> callForcastRequest = forcast.getWeatherInfo(Double.toString(lat), Double.toString(lon), "imperial", "API_KEY");
                callRequest.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherOutputData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<WeatherOutputData> call, Response<WeatherOutputData> response) {
                        WeatherOutputData data = response.body();

                        cityNameTextView.setText(data.getName());
                        tempTextView.setText(data.getMain().getTemp() + "°F");
                        description.setText("Clouds: " + data.getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                        humidityTextView.setText("Humidity: " + data.getMain().getHumidity() + "%");
                        pressureTextView.setText("Pressure: " + data.getMain().getPressure() + "ppi");
                        windSpeedTextView.setText("Wind Speed: " + data.getWind().getSpeed() + " MPH");
                        String icon = data.getWeather().get(0).getIcon();
                        String iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png";
                        //Picasso.get().load(iconUrl).into(weatherIcon);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<WeatherOutputData> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("null",t.getMessage());
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        try{
            if(mLocationPermissionsGranted){
                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                            lat =  currentLocation.getLatitude();
                            lon =  currentLocation.getLongitude();
                        }else{
                            Log.d("null", "onComplete: current location is null");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e("tag", "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
    }



    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d("tag", "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;

            }else{
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("tag", "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch(requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d("tag", "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("tag", "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would go in the fragment.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting the EPERM (Operation not permitted) error?

Answer (score 0):

Write the complete code in onViewCreated() method.It makes sure that view is created

Comment: you mean onCreateView()?

Comment: NO.There is an overrided method called onViewCreated() in fragments and write your code inside that method

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is getting permission and location in Activity.
Connect your fragment and Activity by Interface. In fact you can send location request to activity from fragment and after handling permission and finding location you have access to fragment and you can write a method in fragment to call from activity for passing location results.

Comment: I put the getDeviceLocation() and getLocationPermission() in the main activity, and tried to access those methods by using ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getLocationPermission(); however, I'm still getting the socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) error